# Iterating over glob patterns, not the files in them

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards, for

I would like to perform the same aggregation operations on each of several bunches of files where each bunch is matched by one glob pattern. What I would not like to do is pipe each file name into the aggregation function separately.

My first attempt failed because the file names got globbed in the outer loop, flattening the whole collection into a flat list and not treating them as separate batches:

```
for fileglob in /path/to/bunch*1 /path/to/bunch*2 ... ; do
  stat "$fileglob" | awk [aggregation]
done
```

So I hid the `*` from the loop by escaping it, then unescaped it for the function:

```
for fileglob in /path/to/bunch*1 /path/to/bunch*2 ... ; do
  realglob=`echo "$fileglob" | sed 's/\\//g'`
  stat "$realglob" | awk [aggregation]
done
```

There has to be a better way. What is it?

**GNU bash, version 3.2.51**

Comment: Wat is your input and desired output?  I'm not sure if people can read minds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires a careful use of quotes:

```
for fileglob in '/path/to/bunch*1' '/path/to/bunch*2' ... ; do
    stat $fileglob | awk [aggregation]
done
```

But that may fail on filenames with spaces (or newlines). Better to use this:

```
fileglobs=("/path/to/bunch*1" "/path/to/bunch*2")

for aglob in "${fileglobs[@]}" ; do
    set -- $aglob
    stat "$@" | awk [aggregation]
done
```

The glob gets correctly expanded and placed in the positional parameters with:

```
set -- $aglob
```

Then, each parameter is placed as an argument to `stat` in:

```
stat "$@"
```

And the output of `stat` goes (as one output) to `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your glob patterns in single quotes to avoid having them interpreted in the outer loop.

```
for fileglob in '/path/to/bunch*1' '/path/to/bunch*2' ; do
stat "$fileglob" | awk [aggregation]
done
```

I haven't tested this because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I did run a similar test.

*Without quotes*

```
for a in a* b*; do
echo $a
done
```

*Output*

```
$ ./test.sh
abc
ade
atlmfc.zip
bce
bin
```

*With quotes*

```
for a in 'a*' 'b*'; do
echo $a
done
```

*Output*

```
$ ./test.sh
abc ade atlmfc.zip
bce bin
```

Basically, the glob gets interpreted by echo instead of by the loop. Thus there are two lines of output, one for each glob.